# how to copy records of excel to exsist table in data base in Webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I have an excel sheet of 1400 records.
So Ineed to copy them to exsisting table in my data base.
I try many times to do that in elegant way but...nothing.
I looking for simple method to do that without code..

How can I do that?

I'd be grateful to anyone who can explain me all the process...

thanks again..

Comment: Do you want simply to copy your Excel records into a db table of your project before to deploy your site or do you want to create a function that, once activated, uploads an Excel file to your site and transfers its records into a table? Which db are you using?

Comment: Hay..The moderator of my final project sent me a list of finnacial records and I want to pass the content into the table just once, and continue to build the web site and to base on this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Sql CE as database server, the best solution is to convert your Excel file into CSV and import the CSV file using [SQL Server Compact Standalone Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/69910).

You can find a thread that outlines the procedure at this link: [Loading Comma Delimited Text Data Into WebMatrix](http://forums.asp.net/t/1828672.aspx/1?Loading+Comma+Delimited+Text+Data+Into+WebMatrix).

Otherwise, if you are using MS SQL Server, SQL Server Management Studio makes available an exhaustive SQL Server Import and Export Wizard with a lot of functions.